# AppEngine and Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have created an application in Django with google_appengine 1.7.7 
When I run

```
./dev_appserver.py mysite
```

It gives me the error

```
No valid OAuth 2.0 credentials.  Before using the Google SQL Service backend on dev_appserver, you must first run "manage.py syncdb" and proceed through the given instructions to fetch an OAuth 2.0 token.
```

It runs successfully on appspot but not running on localhost.
Whats the problem?

Comment: Did you follow that instruction? What happened?

Comment: Yes , i have followed that instruction , same problem arise.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is having a problem similar to this and finds this page, please see the bug referenced here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9006